# Hover effect for QTextDocument

Tags: python, pyside2, qtextdocument

I wanted to have some hover effect over `p` tag inside [`QTextDocument`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtGui/QTextDocument.html).

I have tried to set QSS for `QTextDocument` using `QTextDocument().setDefaultStyleSheet()`.
Here's what the result I have obtained;

[image: output]

Script;

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets


class Test(QtWidgets.QTextBrowser):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.document().setDefaultStyleSheet(
            """
p.out{
    background-color: "orange";
    color: "black";
}

p.out:hover{
    background-color: "yellow";
}
"""
        )

        self.setStyleSheet(
            """
QTextBrowser{
    background-color: "black";
    color: "white";
}
""")

        self.setHtml(
            """
<p class='out'> Checking this </p>
"""
        )


test = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

sample = Test()
sample.show()

test.exec_()
```

**Color attribute inside qss worked but the hover doesn't work.**

Is there any way of achieving hover effect over *fragments of text* inside document?

Comment: Pseudo class selectors are not supported in Qt rich text. In fact, it only supports a [limited subset of HTML/CSS](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html#supported-css-selectors). If you want support for element hover, it can only be done by complex handling of mouse movements on the widget that shows the document *and* by actually altering the text document fragments by setting their text options. That is **not** easy, nor simple. Unfortunately, that's how Qt rich text works, which is more oriented in performance than advanced features. Consider using a QWebEngineView instead.

Comment: Thank you, I thought `QTextBlock` or `QTextFrame` would, but I couldn't. I will use QWebEngineView, again thanks!

Comment: You're right, QTextBlock is what should be accessed in your case (since you're trying to highlight paragraphs), but, as said, it's not easy, as you should keep track of every previous state before changing its format, and then *carefully* restore it back. As said, it *can* be done, but it's difficult and most of the times it's not worth it. On the other hand, using QWebEngine adds an important dependency, which impacts on memory and is not part of a default Qt installation.

Comment: Does it need to be a `QTextDocument`? If no, just use QML instead, it's the preferred way to create UIs anyway and should make this a lot easier.

Comment: @dreua sorry for the late response, I currently haven't implemented QML yet and am not much aware of it. I prefer `QTextDocument`  since we can easily modify contents through python script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Understanding, QTextDocument's [structure](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qtforpython-5.14/overviews/richtext-structure.html#rich-text-document-structure) and [Syntax Highlighter](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qtforpython-5.12/PySide2/QtGui/QSyntaxHighlighter.html). We can modify [QTextBlock](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtGui/QTextBlock.html)'s [Format](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qtforpython-5.12/PySide2/QtGui/QTextCharFormat.html#) whenever we want. I tried to change it's format using enterEvent, and restore format in leaveEvent.

we can modify box model using [QTextFrame](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtGui/QTextFrame.html#) using [QTextFrameFormat](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtGui/QTextFrameFormat.html#PySide2.QtGui.PySide2.QtGui.QTextFrameFormat).

```py
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui


class High(QtGui.QSyntaxHighlighter):
    def __init__(self, doc):
        super().__init__(doc)

        self._formats = tuple(
            QtGui.QTextCharFormat() for _ in range(2)
        )

        self._formats[1].setForeground(
            QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor("orange"))
        )

        self._formats[1].setFontWeight(3)
        self._formats[1].setFontUnderline(True)
        self._formats[1].setFontPointSize(12)

    def highlightBlock(self, text: str):
        self.setFormat(
            0, len(text), self._formats[self.currentBlockState() if self.currentBlockState() > -1 else 0]
        )


class Sample(QtWidgets.QTextBrowser):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.lighter = High(self.document())
        self._prev = None

        self.insertBlock("This is a sample line\n")
        self.insertBlock("Can also be a\nparagraph thing\n")
        self.insertBlock("it's a block, Bye!")

    def insertBlock(self, text):
        cur = self.textCursor()
        cur.block().setUserState(0)  # default: -1

        cur.insertText(text)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, eve):
        super().mouseMoveEvent(eve)

        cur = self.cursorForPosition(eve.pos())

        if cur.block() == self._prev:
            return

        self.restore()
        cur.block().setUserState(1)
        self.lighter.rehighlightBlock(cur.block())

        self._prev = cur.block()

    def restore(self):
        if not self._prev:
            return

        self._prev.setUserState(0)
        self.lighter.rehighlightBlock(self._prev)
        self._prev = None

    def leaveEvent(self, eve):
        self.restore()
        super().leaveEvent(eve)


testing = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
sample = Sample()
sample.show()
testing.exec_()
```

Comment: Note that there's no need to "reset" the format, as QSyntaxHighlighter already takes care of that; in fact, you should *not* set the format at all if you don't need highlighting. Just create a single format and do `if self.currentBlockState(): self.setFormat(0, len(text), self.myformat)`. It is also a bad idea to change any aspect of the font that might alter its bounding rect (point size, weight, but also letter spacing), as it could lead to relayouting of the text and make the text jump around while moving the mouse.

Comment: QSyntaxHighlighter does appy formats but its not responsive to events. and yes it's a bad idea, but if we could specify and calculate it's bound according text font size, we could avoid jumping out of rect bounds

Comment: I was referring to the use of `setFormat()` with an empty QTextCharFormat, which is pointless: being it empty, it doesn't do anything. If the block state has been reset, the block will be reset to its original format; the highlighter only updates the underlying QTextLayout of the text block, it doesn't override its current character format(s); `rehighlightBlock` *first* restores the existing "real" formats of the block, then does whatever `highlightBlock` does. Try changing `highlightBlock()` to `if self.currentBlockState() > 0: self.setFormat(0, len(text), self._formats[1])` and you'll see.

Comment: QSyntaxHighlighter *does* react to document changes (QTextDocument's [`contentsChange`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#contentsChange), which can also be manually emitted). Changing the block state or data obviously doesn't trigger that, and that's why `rehighlightBlock()` is required, but it technically does the same as a document content change, with the difference that it already knows what block it has to specifically rehighlight. I'm not sure what you meant in the second part of your comment. Are you suggesting to implement `highlightBlock` to compute sizes for the new format?